Alert setup in Pine
I am trading on the monthly and sometimes weekly chart and want to test a strategy whereby I get an alert when certain conditions are met during the course of the traded timeframe.
These conditions can change over the course of the week or month. However, when setting up the alert options are:

only once
once per bar close
once per minute
once per bar

For my strategy once per minute is most likely solution but then I get bombarded with hundreds of alerts.
I was wondering if there is any solution ?
Appreciate your help.
Thank you
I tried setting up alerts to be triggered only when condition is met however when adding them on TradingView the four options,I can only choose once per minute which is causing a big headache to track
